# EasyMock - expect a method call that throws a checked exception

Tags: junit, easymock

I have the follow method that rethrows the JMSException wrapped in a RuntimeException so my code doesn't have to deal with the checked exception.

```
public String getText(TextMessage textMessage) {
    try {
        return textMessage.getText();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use EasyMock, asking that the getText method throws a JMSException when called, so that I can then test that a RuntimeException is thrown.

```
@Test
public void getText() {
    TextMessage mockMessage = createMock(TextMessage.class);
    expect(mockTextMessage.getText()).andThrow(new JMSException("Something terrible happened"));
    replayAll();
    jmsHelper.getText(mockTextMessage);
    verifyAll();
}
```

I'm getting a *Unhandled exception type JMSException* compilation error against the expect(mockTextMessage.getText()) code.

What's the best way to write this EasyMock test?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing just fine.  All you have to do is make the compiler happy by making your test method throw the JMSException

```
@Test
public void getText() throws JMSException{
   ... 
}
```

The error is just because the compiler doesn't know mockTextMessage.getText() is a fake method so you have to catch or throw any exceptions it throws.  Don't worry, this will never actually throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have done but I don't like it at all. If a developer picks this up they see the test declaring that it could throw an Exception it can't. Confusing from the outset. I'm off to have a look at the other mocking frameworks to see what they do. Thanks for your response

Comment: All mocking frameworks would all do that because the method throws a checked exception.  It doesn't really hurt readability.  You could also make the method `throws Exception` to cover all possibilities